# Broadleafdemo with Terracotta BigMemory

Tags: terracotta, broadleaf-commerce

I'm trying to figure out how to configure Broadleaf eCommerce java solution with Terracotta BigMemory
Listening to http://www.slideshare.net/crederajfischer/bigmemory-for-bigproblems-improving-performance-of-a-real-world-ecommerce-application-based-on-hibernate-broadleaf-commerce

1. How do I configure Broadleafdemo to use Terracotta BigMemory ? 
   Is it as simple as modifying bl-override-ehcache.xml to have a 'offheap' component ?
2. I guess I have to have a license to use Terracotta BigMemory ?

Answer (score 1):

Configuring Broadleaf Commerce (specifically the demo) for BigMemory is actually quite easy. In the webinar, the focus is on the concept of the Broadleaf Commerce "Hydrated Cache", which is a separate but related concept to the Hibernate level 2 cache that most people think of. To configure the hydrated cache in the demo application for BigMemory, you would need to:

1. In bl-override-ehcache.xml, in the cacheEventListenerFactory element, add a properties attribute that specifies the BigMemory manager class: properties="managerClass=org.broadleafcommerce.profile.cache.engine.BigMemoryHydratedCacheManagerImpl"
2. You can optionally add a cache region called "hydrated-offheap-cache" to your ehcache.xml that defines an off-heap cache region and the BigMemory hydrated cache manager will use it, otherwise it will create one for you.
3. Make sure you start your container with the appropriate vm arguments to allow the direct memory access that BigMemory requires (e.g. -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1500M)

Otherwise, if you simply want to add a BigMemory cache to the demo for your own programmatic access, or if you want to create a BigMemory cache region that Hibernate uses for its level 2 cache, then it is as simple as modifying the override-ehcache.xml. This page provides a great reference for working with BigMemory caches in your ehcache.xml:

http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/bigmemory

As for your second question, yes, BigMemory is a commercial product and does require a license. They do, however, offer a trial download.